# How to detect the collision with a surface as optimized as possible in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, collision-detection, collision, collider

I have two colliders (of any type) and I would like to know if there is any optimized way to detect the collision of one trigger (SphereCollider for example) with the surface of the other (this is basically that by entering and staying on the surface of the object (mesh) gives collision and that being outside or inside the object there is no type of collision. I know I can achieve this effect by making a collider of the mesh surface but that would increase the number of polygons and I don't know if it could be the most optimized (since for example in a cube its surface would be basically 6 cubes)

Comment: the best thing to do is to use colliders with primitive shape that approximate the shape of the mesh collider. Check [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/when-would-a-mesh-collider-be-better-than-primitive-colliders)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay But isn't there a more creative and less consuming way to do it? perhaps, for example, when colliding with the cube it has an attached camera and this indicates if the other collider has a mesh in front or not (opacity), or with mathematical calculations of the limit of the object ..., some way that works in (almost) all cases without change the structure of colliders a lot. The main problem is that a mesh has practically zero depth, so adding primitives would be a bit inaccurate in some cases